# VS Code keeps adding incorrect Java import / How to prevent specific imports from being added?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

VS Code's Red Hat Java extension keeps adding these two lines near the top of my source code every time I try to compile. These imports cause my compile to fail because they conflict with my code and other imports. How do I suppress this troublesome behaviour?

```
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.swing.Action;
```

I already disabled "organize imports on save". This makes no difference.

Comment: if you don't use those imports anywhere in your project, you could try using the `java.completion.filteredTypes` setting. Not sure if that works. But really what I'm more interested in is why this is happening. Do classes named `Context` and `Action` show up in that file?

Comment: Try also doing an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Comment: Yes, the code contains classes with those names, but these are imported from other places (I don't think I can share the code); that's why the added imports cause conflicts.

I'll see if I can do a bisect. It may take some time as the problem doesn't seem to occur on every save action and I don't yet have an exact sequence of actions that consistently triggers it.

Comment: Check whether there are other settings in settings.json to cause this phenomenon? Or restore the default settings to see if there is no longer an automatic introduction.

Comment: After setting `java.completion.filteredTypes` to exclude the added types, the problem has not appeared for at least a week, so that seems to have solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(posting my comment as an answer since the asker seems satisfied with it)

If you don't use those imports anywhere in your project, you could try using the `java.completion.filteredTypes` setting. Its description reads as follows:

> Defines the type filters. All types whose fully qualified name matches the selected filter strings will be ignored in content assist or quick fix proposals and when organizing imports. For example 'java.awt.*' will hide all types from the awt packages.

It takes an array. Its default value is this:

```json
[
  "java.awt.*",
  "com.sun.*",
  "sun.*",
  "jdk.*",
  "org.graalvm.*",
  "io.micrometer.shaded.*"
]
```

Comment: Ah, right, I see now that organizing imports is mentioned in its description, even though its name doesn't really suggest that. Thanks!